# If for two sets of sets (not same sets) $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_n = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_n$, then can I conclude on $\mu(E_n)=\mu(F_n)$?

Tags: measure-theory

If for two sets of sets (not same sets) $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_n = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_n$, then can I conclude on $\mu(E_n)=\mu(F_n)$?

The theory says that

$$\mu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n)$$

But why would this mean that $\mu(E_n)=\mu(F_n)$?

Comment: What do you mean by the sum inside the measure?  It also doesn't make sense to bring the sum outside the measure as that would only apply when the $E_n$'s are (almost) disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, this will not hold.  Let $A$ be a set with positive measure.

Suppose that $E_n=A$ for $n$ odd and $E_n=\emptyset$ for $n$ even.

Similarly, suppose that $F_n=A$ for $n$ even and $F_n=\emptyset$ for $n$ odd.

Observe that $E_n\not=F_n$ for all $n$.

In this case $\mu(E_n)\not=\mu(F_n)$ for all $n$ (one is zero and the other is positive), but the unions of the sets are the same ($A$).

Comment: But on the other hand, my question might be related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376681/existence-of-lebesgue-measurable-set-with-the-same-outer-measure-of-the-given-se

Comment: I do not see any deep connections between your question and the linked question.  Perhaps you should add additional context.

Comment: Well I was expecting that the idea in the linked question would allow perhaps constructing unions s.t. the measures agree.

Comment: You can make the measures agree by setting $E_n$ equal to $F_n$.  Perhaps it would be helpful to ask about what you really what to have happen.  The answer to the current question is no, general unions don't agree term-by-term.  This doesn't mean that you can't construct a pair with some interesting properties.

Comment: But that's too trivial. I also found about translation invariance of the measures which would also allow doing making them equal. I wonder if there are more techniques than these? Not, since how could the measures be same unless "they're 'essentially' the same 'cover'"?

Comment: There are many many ways to make the measures equal or not equal (as desired).  There are so many possibilities and very little structure needed, that it is likely impossible to describe all cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, and a simple example would be $E_n=[-1,1]$ for all $n\geq 0$, and $F_0=[-1,1]$ and $F_n=\{0\}$ for $n\geq 1$.

In this case, $\cup_nE_n=\cup_n F_n=[-1,1]$ but $\mu(E_n)=2$ while $\mu(F_n)=0$ for $n>0$ ($\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure on reals).